# What's the meaning of the notes here？

Tags: java, performance, exception, jvm

I am learning the source code of `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` of JDK8, and I do not know the purpose of the 'null check' here:

```
/**
 * Returns previous node, or throws NullPointerException if null.
 * Use when predecessor cannot be null.  The null check could
 * be elided, but is present to help the VM.
 *
 * @return the predecessor of this node
 */
final Node predecessor() throws NullPointerException {
    Node p = prev;
    if (p == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    else
        return p;
}
```

The notes tell us the null check could be elided, but is present to help the VM - why? What's the benefit for the VM?

Comment: No idea, but guessing : maybe that helps the just in time compiler do a better job. But why exactly, that could (if at all) say a person who really knows the internals of the jvm...

Comment: I edited your question and added some tags. Hopefully someone who knows the details will see it.

Comment: The code and the comment was written long ago; it's probably not actual for the current JVM. I suppose the idea was to hoist the null check manually, so that JVM could treat all subsequent uses of the variable as always-non-null and eliminate implicit null checks while accessing Node's fields.

Answer (score 0):

From a design perspective, when you're writing an API, it's good to pass the responsibility of handling undefined behaviour to the user, rather than attempting to handle it yourself.

In the comments, it says that you should only use `predecessor()` when it cannot be `null`, therefore it checks to make sure it isn't `null` - but if it is, then the behaviour is undefined and you should notify the user.

Maybe there's something specific to the JVM that it's useful for, but someone with better knowledge of it will have to speak to that.

Comment: thanks a lot. But I still do not know the benefit for VM.